# Entity Framework Code First - Invalid column name Discriminator

Tags: ef-code-first

Two Classes in codefirst

```
public partial class BaseEntity 
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
}

public partial class Fund : BaseEntity
{
   public int Name { get; set; }
}
public partial class InvestorFund : BaseEntity 
{
  public int FundID { get; set; }
}
```

Mapping Classes

```
this.Property(t => t.ID).HasColumnName("FundID");
```

My Code First Join SQL Query

```
from fund in context.Funds

join investorFund in context.InvestorFunds on fund.ID equals investorFund.FundID
```

Throws an `Invalid column name Discriminator`

Answer (score 10):

You need to tell Code First how these classes relate to tables. There are three options:

- **Table per type (TPT)** would mean the fields defined on Fund and InvestorFund would go into their own tables and properties defined on BaseEntity would go to a table named BaseEntity. Querying would be slower as each entity now has to combine the fields from multiple tables.

  ```
  modelBuilder.Entity<Fund>().ToTable("Funds");
  modelBuilder.Entity<InvestorFund>().ToTable("InvestorFunds");
  ```
- **Table per heirarchy (TPH)** would mean that Fund, InvestorFund and BaseEntity properties would all be merged into a single table named BaseEntity and an extra field would be required to indicate which row is which type. This extra field is called the *discriminator*.

  ```
  modelBuilder.Entity<BaseEntity>()
    .Map<Fund>(m => m.Requires("Discriminator").HasValue("F"))
    .Map<InvestorFund>(m => m.Requires("Discriminator").HasValue("I"));
  ```
- **Table per concrete type (TPC)** would mean that Fund and InvestorFund each have their own table which would also include any fields needed for their base classes.

  ```
  modelBuilder.Entity<Fund>().Map(m => {
                m.MapInheritedProperties();
                m.ToTable("Funds"); 
  }); 
  modelBuilder.Entity<InvestorFund>().Map(m => {
                m.MapInheritedProperties();
                m.ToTable("InvestorFunds"); 
  });
  ```

Comment: You should be able to use the code lines I wrote under TPT to avoid this error.

Comment: In this example the "Type" should be "Discriminator".

Comment: What implications does this have in the mapping as in a "NoteMap" class

Comment: What is a "NoteMap" ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to run migrations.

Go to package manager console, then type `update-database` after you enable automatic migrations.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Migrations.